# How to use only() method in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am having one issue ....

```
required_fields = needed_fileds()//THis function will return the required fields
```

Example

```
required_fields = ['first_name','last_name','contact_number'] // Required Fields inside a list
```

How do I make a query set with ony() method

```
obj = Profile.objects.only(required_fields) //
```

Currently showing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) takes field names as positional arguments. To convert a list (or any iterable) into positional arguments you can use the `*` operator

```
obj = Profile.objects.only(*required_fields)
```

Comment: It showing an error "'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
"

Comment: Add the code that’s raising the error and the full trace back to the question

Comment: Can I ask you one doubt ....

If I fetch a query using only method can I access the remaining fields using that object?

Comment: Example  required_fields ['first_name','last_name','age']

Comment: query = Person.objects.only(*required_fields)

Comment: can I able to access query.address?

Comment: @David there is a performance penalty in doing so. Django has to perform a database query to get the field value that you access

Comment: @David if you will be accessing other fields then there is not much point in using `only`

Comment: My requirement is I need to show only this fields required_fields in templte....

But this issue is in template we are calling all thease things fields in template

Comment: In tempalte {{query.address}}

But I don't want to show this

Comment: You probably don't need to use `only`... just grab everything and display whatever